# Linq to SQL Data context doesnt commit if multiple inserts are called on table with auto increment

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I am having an issue when trying to submit two inserts at once. The table has a auto increment primary key. The comment objects set up dont have there ID value set so that the database can assign this.

My code works for single inserts if i submit straight away but if i try and do multiple InsertOnSubmit commands then it seems to do nothign, and returns no errors or exceptions even though my code is within a try and catch block. Has anyone else had this problem or do you know which direction i should be looking?

Example 1 (This doesn't commit to the database)

```
//myComment is initialised with data
dc.tblDailyComments.InsertOnSubmit(myComment);


//myComment2 is initialised with different data
dc.tblDailyComments.InsertOnSubmit(myComment2); 


//when this is called it does not commit to the database   
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Example 2 (This works fine)

```
//myComment is initialised with data
dc.tblDailyComments.InsertOnSubmit(myComment);

//commits to the database   
dc.SubmitChanges();

//myComment2 is initialised with different data
dc.tblDailyComments.InsertOnSubmit(myComment2); 


//commits to the database   
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Anyone got any ideas for this? im sure it is a simple fix i just can't seem to see anyone having the same problem. Cheers

Comment: I suspect there must be something else going on, because that should work as far as I can tell.  Unfortunately, my linq-to-sql-fu is weak, and my psychic debugging skills fail in your case.

Comment: It only fails to do the inserts if the table is completely empty, if i manually put the first entry into the table it appears to work which doesnt seem to make sense.

Comment: This sounds alot like a problem I've had myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074611/insertallonsubmit-only-inserts-first-data-record Alas, I did not find a solution other than submitting after each insert.

Comment: I've reported the issue as a bug to Microsoft: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074611/insertallonsubmit-only-inserts-first-data-record/1298094#1298094

Comment: cheers mate, nice to hear im not the only one that had this issue! thought i was just missing the basics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reported as issue by Michael Barth to Microsoft

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=483711

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to add all your comments to a collection and call the InsertAllOnSubmit() method instead? Does that work?