# InsertAllOnSubmit only inserts 1 record then throws exception

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Trying to insert a collection into Database using Linq's InsertAllOnSubmit.  The Issue I have is that it inserts one record, then thrown an exception stating  "Cannot add an entity that already exists"

```
public static void INSERT_LoadDetails(List<LoadDetail> newLoadDetails)
{
    try
    {
        using (ImpactDataContext IDC = new ImpactDataContext())
        {
            IDC.LoadDetails.InsertAllOnSubmit(newLoadDetails);
            IDC.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e; // EXCEPTION: Cannot add an entity that already exists.
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried:
I have verified that the collection being passed does indeed contain more than 1 record. Database has PK and Identity is set to Auto-generate.  No FK constraints exist on database.  dbml is up-to-date and matches DB. Collection being passed does not have ID passed as DB handles that. Tried changing to looping structure and using InsertOnSubmit() - same result

The following post did not help
[InsertAllOnSubmit only inserts first data record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074611/insertallonsubmit-only-inserts-first-data-record)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Quent

Comment: Debug and view the `List` being passed in.  Check for any constraints on database (e.g. username must be unique).

Comment: Post the exception ToString so that we can see all information that is available.

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to insert multiple records in one hit then try changing the approach to SqlBulkCopy. 
hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with SqlBulkCopy, but not the approach I'm working with here - But thanks regardless.